# What value to choose as representative of 100 votes?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I'm trying to use many votes to cast one vote. There are only 4 options, and I'm trying to use "consensus" to decide which to pick.

100 people vote. They can vote 1, 2, 3, or 4 stars. Distribution: 1 = 33, 2 = 26, 3 = 13, and 4 = 28. What star rating would you say is representative of these 100 people: 2.36 (2), the average, or 1, the most common choice?

Also, if the average was 1.625, what star rating would you select: 1 or 2?

Why?

Comment: The average number of stars must indicate that context is important. Otherwise, would you analyze this data in the same way if the choices were not 1,2,3, or 4 but rather A, B, C, and D instead? You can't quite take an "average" of letters; is it important to interpret the stars as numerical values or just categories?

Comment: Why do you think that a single number will somehow be "representative" of a distribution? A [simple descriptive picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/llI0v.png) would be far better.

Comment: @r.e.s. I'm trying to use many votes to cast one vote. There are only 4 options, and I'm trying to use "consensus" to decide which to pick.

Comment: @Xoque55 it's a continuous range from 1 to 4 broken up into 4 discrete values (like picking a rating while giving a review on Amazon).

Answer (score 1):

As described, your observed values in terms of 'stars' are clearly ordinal. That means both the 'mode' and the 'median' are legitimate
ways to express a 'typical' value.

The 'mode' is the most frequent value, '1 star' in your case.

The 'median' is found by sorting the values in order and picking
the middle one of the sorted values. (You can think of 'ordinal' as meaning 'sortable') You have 33 at '1 star'
and 26 at '2 stars'. Technically, there is no middle value
out of 100, but values 50 and 51 in the ordered list agree,
so the median is '2 stars'.

The 'mean'. If you are willing to take '1 star' as meaning 1 of something, '2 stars' as meaning 2 (twice as many), '3 stars' as 3, and '4 stars' as 4, then you can consider that you have numerical data, and the mean makes sense. It is found by summing the 100
numbers and dividing by 100. You have already done that to get
2.36. There is no reason that the mean must be an integer, but
you can round 2.36 if you like.

In order for adding the numbers to make sense, you have to
believe that they are genuine. For example, is '4 stars' somehow
worth four times as much as '1 star'.

In an academic setting, letter grades are truly ordinal (that is,
they can be sorted in order). We often assign fake numbers to
the letter grades, such as A=4, B=3, C=2, and so on. Even though it is
a stretch to say someone with an A has learned or accomplished
twice as much as someone who got a C, we do this anyway. The
reasons are historical and to an extent computational. While it
is clear that someone who has a GPA of 3.97 is a 'better' student
than someone who has a GPA of 2.11, it is unwise to take the
exact numbers really seriously.

Whether to use the mode, median, or mean in your case is a judgment
call. None of these really fits with the sharpest meaning of
'consensus' because that would imply everyone agrees, which
I suppose will rarely be the case for your data.

> You can use the mode (most common opinion), the median (roughly half
>   say worse, roughly half say better), or the mean (if you think 'stars'
>   are things that can be counted like numbers). It is up to your
>   understanding of the what the stars mean and what you think best
>   distills the differing votes of 100 people into a single
>   useful 'opinion'. No method is perfect, each has potential
>   strengths. I'd say, make your choice and argue the case for it.

Maybe it is helpful to think about two ways of conducting an election.
Four candidates are running for mayor of a city. Suppose the 
candidate with the most votes got only 45% of the total vote, 
and the other three 14%, 15% and 26% of the vote, respectively.
In some voting systems the guy with 45% is elected mayor. In that
town, the 'modal' vote is sufficient.

But someone might argue
that 55% of the people don't want him. Maybe a runoff election
of the top two candidates (with 45% and 26%) would see a coalition
vote, so that the guy with 45% would get 45% again and the guy with
26% on the first try would get all the other votes for a total of 55%, and thus become mayor. This is a little like insisting
on getting a median opinion in the runoff election before declaring a mayor.

One of the comments (@r.e.s.) suggested a graphic display suggested using graphic displays. In the four barplots below, the modal bar is colored black and the median bar is dark blue. The modal and median bars need not be adjacent. In some cases it is not obvious how the data can be 'fairly' summarized using just the the mode or just the median.

[image]